# How to change the y axis to display percent (%) in Python Plotnine barplot?

Tags: python, bar-chart, visualization, data-science, plotnine

How can we change y axis to percent, instead of a fraction using Plotnine library in Python?

A MWE of a barplot is as follows:

```
from plotnine import *
from plotnine.data import mpg

p = ggplot(mpg) + geom_bar(aes(x='manufacturer', fill='class'), position='fill')
print(p)
```

Which gives the following figure:

[Stacked bar chart with y axis as fraction not percent](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wwx4M.png)

With ggplot2 in R it is simple, just need to add:

```
+ scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent)
```

However I have not been able to find how to do this in Plotnine.

Any advise?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The `labels` parameter accepts a callable that takes the list of break points as input. All you have to do is to convert each item in the list manually:

```
scale_y_continuous(labels=lambda l: ["%d%%" % (v * 100) for v in l])
```

Answer (score 19):

similar question raised here: https://github.com/has2k1/plotnine/issues/152

```
from plotnine import *
from plotnine.data import mpg
from mizani.formatters import percent_format

p = ggplot(mpg) + geom_bar(aes(x='manufacturer', fill='class'), position='fill')
p = p + scale_y_continuous(labels=percent_format())
print(p)
```

other predefined filters can be found here: https://mizani.readthedocs.io/en/stable/formatters.html